# Adding unused factor levels to table

Tags: r

I have data before/after that i want to analyse using McNemar test.

```
before <-c(0,0,0,0,0,0)
after<-c(1,0,0,1,0,0)
table(before,after)

  after
before 0 1
     0 4 2
```

As you probably already guesses problem with that table is that I'm missing theoretically possible "1" level in "before".

Is there a good clean way of creating that additional row with all zeros ?

Comment: Please read the manual (`?table`), and you will find several references to factor _levels_, e.g. `d <- factor(rep(c("A","B","C"), 10), levels = c("A","B","C","D","E"))` et c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `factor` with `levels` specified

```
 table(factor(before, levels=0:1),after)
 #    after
 #   0 1
 # 0 4 2
 # 1 0 0
```

Comment: @MaciejKarczewski So simple that it has already been asked and answered in SO.

Answer (score 2):

Try `before <- factor(rep(0,6),levels = c(0,1))`

Also you can change levels of an existing factor the following way:

```
x <- factor(1:5)
levels(x) <- c(levels(x),"ABC")
```